# detect circle / ellipse in image

Tags: python, opencv

I have the following images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDaP4.jpg

image without staff lines:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/anrWw.jpg

I want to detect the circles / ellipse shapes in the images and get an array of the detected shapes.

I want to detect the large circles and the tiny one.

I tried the following and it fails to detect anything:

```
img = cv2.imread("1.png", 0)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.2, 1, param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)
```

but circles returns None.
thanks.

thank you to fmw42 but his solution doesn't remove all the noise from the following image:

the current solution doesn't work on:

[image]

[image]

solution for filling the ellipse:

```
def fill_ellipse(image):
    copy = np.copy(image)
    if len(copy.shape) > 2:
        copy = cv2.cvtColor(copy, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    des = cv2.bitwise_not(copy)
    _, contour, hier = cv2.findContours(des, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for cnt in contour:
        cv2.drawContours(des, [cnt], 0, 255, -1)
    res = cv2.bitwise_not(des)
    return res
```

and now I use the solution given by @fmw42 on the filled image (only if I know already that I have a hollow ellipse in the image otherwise this will fail)

Comment: Use morphology to remove the lines. Then get the contours of the round regions or use connected components to get the round regions. Then for each region (draw filled on black) and fit ellipse.

Comment: @fmw42 thank you, but my knowledge of computer vision is quite limited. I did manage to get an image without the staff lines. and i've added a link to said image. can you assist with code?

Comment: Next, get rid of the vertical lines so you only have ellipses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better variation in Python/OpenCV. In addition to filtering on area, we can filter on how good a match the shape is of the contour to a fitted ellipse.

Input 1:

[image]

Input 2:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('notes.png')
#img = cv2.imread('notes2.png')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,128,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# do morphology remove horizontal lines
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,5))
lines1 = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations = 1)

# do morphology to remove vertical lines
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,1))
lines2 = cv2.morphologyEx(lines1, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations = 1)
lines2 = cv2.threshold(lines2,128,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# invert lines2
lines2 = 255 - lines2

# get contours
cntrs = cv2.findContours(lines2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cntrs = cntrs[0] if len(cntrs) == 2 else cntrs[1]

# filter contours on area and draw good ones as black filled on white background
result = np.full_like(img, (255,255,255))
for cntr in cntrs:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cntr)
    if area > 9 and area < 400:
        # get centroid
        M = cv2.moments(cntr)
        cx = M["m10"] / M["m00"]
        cy = M["m01"] / M["m00"]
        pt="(" + str(cx) + "," + str(cy) + ")"
        # fit ellipse
        ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(cntr)
        (x, y), (minor_axis, major_axis), angle = ellipse
        poly = cv2.ellipse2Poly((int(x), int(y)), (int(major_axis / 2), int(minor_axis / 2)), int(angle), 0, 360, 1)
        similarity = cv2.matchShapes(poly.reshape((poly.shape[0], 1, poly.shape[1])), cntr, cv2.CONTOURS_MATCH_I1, 0)
        if similarity < 0.2:
            print("area:",area, "center:",pt, "major_axis:",major_axis, "minor_axis:",minor_axis, "similarity:",similarity)
            cv2.drawContours(result, [cntr], 0, (0,0,0), -1)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("notes_lines_removed.png", result)
#cv2.imwrite("notes2_lines_removed.png", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("lines1", lines1)
cv2.imshow("lines2", lines2)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result 1:

[image]

```
area: 360.0 center: (12.710648148148147,19.85972222222222) major_axis: 30.517166137695312 minor_axis: 18.602985382080078 similarity: 0.0965383677685383
area: 309.0 center: (64.38619201725997,10.55393743257821) major_axis: 24.558181762695312 minor_axis: 16.582275390625 similarity: 0.026244617612192156
```

Result 2:

[image]

```
area: 317.0 center: (12.773922187171397,10.570452155625656) major_axis: 25.237092971801758 minor_axis: 16.553726196289062 similarity: 0.008516408232928263
```

Comment: this fails with the first image - the one with the big circle and the tiny one, I'm even getting the following error:  cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) C:\Miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv-suite_1534379934306\work\modules\imgproc\src\shapedescr.cpp:310: error: (-201:Incorrect size of input array) There should be at least 5 points to fit the ellipse in function 'cv::fitEllipse'

Comment: seems for me that changing cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE to cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE works better because it detect the big circles AND the tiny one while removing all the noise

Comment: That is fine and probably better for small regions as it will give a better contour to match to the polygon. I made the change in my answer. You may need to tune the similarity threshold as I had only 3 ellipses to test.

Comment: hey any chance you'll try to get the 2 new images I added to the post? it fails on them. thanks

Comment: They are not filled, so that is the cause.  Perhaps use morphology to fill them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach using Python/OpenCV.  Basically, remove the horizontal and vertical lines. Then get and filter contours on area.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('notes.png')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,128,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# do morphology remove horizontal lines
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,5))
lines1 = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations = 1)

# do morphology to remove vertical lines
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,1))
lines2 = cv2.morphologyEx(lines1, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations = 1)
lines2 = cv2.threshold(lines2,128,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# invert lines2
lines2 = 255 - lines2

# get contours
cntrs = cv2.findContours(lines2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cntrs = cntrs[0] if len(cntrs) == 2 else cntrs[1]

# filter contours on area and draw good ones as black filled on white background
result = np.full_like(img, (255,255,255))
for cntr in cntrs:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cntr)
    if area > 9 and area < 400:
        # get centroid
        M = cv2.moments(cntr)
        cx = M["m10"] / M["m00"]
        cy = M["m01"] / M["m00"]
        pt="(" + str(cx) + "," + str(cy) + ")"
        print("area:",area,"center:",pt)
        cv2.drawContours(result, [cntr], 0, (0,0,0), -1)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("notes_lines_removed.png", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("lines1", lines1)
cv2.imshow("lines2", lines2)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]

```
area: 360.0 center: (12.710648148148147,19.85972222222222)
area: 309.0 center: (64.38619201725997,10.55393743257821)
```

Comment: I have another image where your solution doesn't remove the rest of the noise and thus i'm getting circles that aren't really circles. I added the image and the result

Comment: If you know you do not have small circles and only the one size ellipse, then increase the `area > 9` to a larger value (larger than the other region).

Comment: that's the problem, I don't know for sure. I need to check either way